# ctypes asynchronous callback from other thread

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, callback, ctypes

I'm trying to receive an async callback from a C thread, but Python crashes everytime such callback is... called.

This is the C callback prototype:

```c
/*! Type declaration for the frame ready callback function.
@sa IC_SetFrameReadyCallback
@sa IC_SetCallbacks
@retval IC_SUCCESS Callback was set successfully
@retval IC_ERROR An error occurred, e.g. hGrabber is NULL.*/
typedef void (*FRAME_READY_CALLBACK)
    (HGRABBER hGrabber, unsigned char* pData, unsigned long frameNumber, void* );
```

And this is the C function to register the callback:

```c
/*! Enable frame ready callback.
@param hGrabber      Handle to a grabber object.
@param cb Callback function of type FRAME_READY_CALLBACK
@param x1_argument_in_void_userdata Pointer to some userdata.
@retval IC_SUCCESS Callback was set successfully
@retval IC_ERROR An error occurred, e.g. hGrabber is NULL.
@sa FRAME_READY_CALLBACK*/
int AC IC_SetFrameReadyCallback(
    HGRABBER                hGrabber,
    FRAME_READY_CALLBACK    cb,
    void*                   x1_argument_in_void_userdata);
```

Finally, this is part of my Python code:

```
FRAME_READY_CALLBACK = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, ICGrabber, POINTER(c_ubyte), c_ulong, c_void_p)

...

library = windll.LoadLibrary('tisgrabber_x64')

...

IC_SetFrameReadyCallback = library.IC_SetFrameReadyCallback
IC_SetFrameReadyCallback.restype = c_int
IC_SetFrameReadyCallback.argtypes = [ICGrabber, FRAME_READY_CALLBACK, c_void_p]

...

def frame_ready(icGrabber, data, frameNumber, unused):
    print "oh"
    #print "Frame", frameNumber, "ready!!!"
    return 1


IC_InitLibrary(0) #library init function

...

IC_SetFrameReadyCallback(hGrabber, FRAME_READY_CALLBACK(frame_ready), None)

...

IC_SoftwareTrigger() #send signal
time.sleep(2) # while sleeping, the C thread calls the.. frame_ready callback
```

Guess what? While sleeping, it crashes!

Comment: `FRAME_READY_CALLBACK` has no return value, so you can use `CFUNCTYPE(None, ...)` and omit the `return` statement in `frame_ready`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the wrong piece of code:

```
IC_SetFrameReadyCallback(hGrabber, FRAME_READY_CALLBACK(frame_ready), None)
```

and here is the working one:

```
cframe_ready = FRAME_READY_CALLBACK(frame_ready)
IC_SetFrameReadyCallback(grab, cframe_ready, None)
```

**The problem:**

I didn't keep a reference to the callback, so the Python garbage collector cleaned it.

Comment: [Callback functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#callback-functions): "Make sure you keep references to `CFUNCTYPE()` objects as long as they are used from C code. ctypes doesn’t, and if you don’t, they may be garbage collected, crashing your program when a callback is made".